# Compact operators on $\ell^p$

Tags: functional-analysis, compactness, lp-spaces, compact-operators

For any real sequence $(a_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}$ define the linear operator $A:\mathbb R ^\mathbb N \to \mathbb R ^\mathbb N$ by $Ax=(a_nx_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}$. Let $1\leq p\leq \infty$.

I know $A$ is a bounded linear operator iff $(a_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}$ is bounded. I want to now characterize the $(a_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}$ for which $A:\ell^p \to \ell^p$ is compact. I know $A$ is compact iff $A$ is bounded and $A(B_1(0))$ is precompact in $\ell^p$. Any hints/ideas how to proceed? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Hint: In general $T$ is compact if and only if there exists a sequence $(T_n)$ such that each $T_n$ has finite rank and $||T-T_n|||to0$.

Comment: So, $a_n \to \infty$ with $T_n$ "stopping at $n$"? 
I've tried characterizing the compact or precompact sets in $\ell^p$ but didn't really get anywhere.